# How to simplify instanceof and ternary operator expression

Tags: java, option-type, conditional-operator, instanceof

Given the following java code.

```
  private PersonEntity bezP(int id, BezEntity fEntity) {
    PersonEntity personB = fEntity.getPersonB();
    if (NP == id) {
      return personB instanceof NpEntity ? personB : null;
    }
    return personB instanceof JpEntity ? personB : null;
  }
```

It seems that the logic is kinda duplicate... but every try to refactor it, did result in more or less the same complexity....

I played around with some `Optionals` expressions... but yeah... what could I try?

Comment: you can have single return statement `return (personB instanceof NpEntity || personB instanceof JpEntity) ? personB : null;`

Comment: but this is actually not the same exactly...

Comment: Honestly, I doubt you can make it any cleaner.  It may be worth pointing out that this is not a common practice, which is probably one reason there is no shorter syntax for it.

Comment: `return (NP == id? personB instanceof NpEntity: personB instanceof JpEntity)? personB: null;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
private PersonEntity bezP(int id, BezEntity fEntity) {
    PersonEntity personB = fEntity.getPersonB();
    return (NP == id ? NpEntity.class : JpEntity.class).isInstance(personB)
        ? personB : null;
}
```

It reduces the number of return statements to 1, but I'd argue your original code is more readable. Alternatively, you could spin out another method:

```
private PersonEntity returnIfMatchingType(Class<?> type, BezEntity fEntity) {
    PersonEntity personB = fEntity.getPersonB();
    return type.isInstance(personB) ? personB : null;
}

private PersonEntity bezP(int id, BezEntity fEntity) {
    return returnIfMatchingType(
        NP == id ? NpEntity.class : JpEntity.class,
        fEntity
    );
}
```

To some degree, it's a matter of taste...